# PHP Mailer suddenly not working anymore

Tags: php, mailer

As part of an online subscription page, I have a PHP mailer that sends the details the user just entered, to 2 specified email addresses. The function has been working fine as far as I can remember but since a week it somehow doesn’t.

Users get the following error message in the browser:

> Failed to add recipient: yyy@yyy.nl [SMTP: Invalid response code
>   received from server (code: 550, response: R1: HELO should be a FQDN
>   or address literal (See RFC 2821
>   4.1.1.1))]_________________________________________MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding:
>   quoted-printable From: xxx@xxx.nl To: yyy@yyy.nl, zzz@zzz.com Date:
>   Tue, 03 Jun 2014 18:18:41 +0200 Subject: Contact formulier Onderstaand
>   bericht is op Tuesday, June 3rd, 2014 om 06:18 PM verstuurd via= het
>   lidworden-contactformulier van de ledensite. Graag actie ondernemen!
>   Subscribtion : Belangstellend lidmaa= tschap Surname :
>
> Name :
>
> Dateofbirth :
>
> Placeofbirth :
>
> Email :
>
> Adres :
>
> Postalcode :
>
> City :
>
> Telephone :
>
> Mobiletelephone :
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /xxxxxxxxxxxxx/sendmail.php:39)
>   in/xxxxxxxxxx.public_html/mailer.php on line 50

This is the code from the `mailer.php`:

```
<?PHP
include("sendmail.php");
    $from = “xxx@xxx.nl";
    $to = “yyy@yyy.nl, zzz@zzz.com";
    $subject = "Contact formulier"; 
    $reply_to = "";

    $date = date ("l, F jS, Y"); 
    $time = date ("h:i A"); 

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $data = $_POST;
} else {
    $data = $_GET;
}

$msg .= "<html>
    <body>
        Message<p>
    <table>\r\n";

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if( strtolower($key) != "submit" ) {    // Ignore submit button
        $msg .= "<tr><td valign='top'>" . ucfirst ($key) . "</td><td>:</td><td>". nl2br($value) . "</td></tr>\n";
        if( $key == "Email" ) {
        $reply_to = $value;
            }
        }
    }

$msg .= "</table>
    </body>
    </html>";

$result = sendmail($from, $to, $reply_to, $subject, $msg, "");

if( $result ) {
    $location="/?page=response_success&menu=lerenvliegen";
} else {
    $location="/?page=response_failure&menu=lerenvliegen";
}
header ("Location:$location"); 
?>
```

Code from `sendmail.php`:

```
<?php
function sendmail($from, $to, $reply_to, $subject, $mailhtml) {
set_include_path("/usr/local/lib/php" . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get(”include_path”));

require_once 'Mail.php';
require_once 'Mail/mime.php';
$host = "localhost";  
$username = "";     
$password = ""; 
$mime = new Mail_mime();
$mime->setHTMLBody($mailhtml);  

if( $reply_to != "") {
    $extraheaders = array('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Date' => date( 'r' ), 'Subject' => $subject, 'Reply-To' => $reply_to, 'Return-Path' => $reply_to);
} else {
    $extraheaders = array('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Date' => date( 'r' ), 'Subject' => $subject);
}
$recipients['To']  = $to;

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
    array ('host' => $host,
    'auth' => false,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));

$body = $mime->get();  
$headers = $mime->headers($extraheaders);
$result = $smtp->send($recipients, $headers, $body);

IF (PEAR::isError($result)):
    echo $result->getMessage() . "_________________________________________" . $mime->getMessage();
    return false;
ENDIF;

return true;
}
```

Am I missing some mistake in the code?

Comment: It's most likely the smart/curly quotes `“`. Beautiful, yet *deadly* `“`.

Comment: What's with the quotes in your code? Ex: `$from = “xxx@xxx.nl";`

Comment: @ Fred, j08691, they just changed when I copied the code in to Textedit to make some privacy alterations to the code.

Comment: it's a SMTP server problem. It warns about an invalid `HELO` format, ie it must be like `HELO smtp.domain.com`. Check the script options, or php smtp settings.

Comment: It appears to me that problem is that your server doesn't have a valid "fully qualified domain name" and the MTA is now rejecting emails the script is trying to send.  Something about your MTA was either changed or upgraded in all probability.  The "Headers already sent" is just a latent bug you always had, in the way the code is written, but it didn't happen because errors weren't occurring.

Comment: @JakeGould That would default to using the defined MTA for the server, whatever that was.  This doesn't look like a coding problem, and you're of course welcome to create a gigantic domain specific answer that is essentially an exercise in teaching debugging and system administration, but your assumption that the system already can't find an MTA is clearly not correct, because the existing MTA is returning the FQDN error.

Comment: @JakeGould You're reading something into my reply that was not intended.  With that said, my point is that this is not a problem with programming, other than that the code was inherently buggy when an SMTP error occurred.  If this is a linux server there are things one would do to debug the problem from a bash shell, but that's system administration related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /xxxxxxxxxxxxx/sendmail.php:39)
>   in/xxxxxxxxxx.public_html/mailer.php on line 50

It seems that somewhere in `sendmail.php` around line 39 headers are already being output ahead of the headers being sent from `mailer.php` around line 50.

Or it could be that something changed on your server to cause an error in `sendmail.php` that would make it output an error around line 39. Which would mean header output was technically already started. So the additional headers being sent out in `mailer.php` around line 50 would choke.

**EDIT:** With the added code from `sendmail.php` in place, I noticed this error check:

```
IF (PEAR::isError($result)):
    echo $result->getMessage() . "_________________________________________" . $mime->getMessage();
    return false;
ENDIF;
```

But looking at your error, this seems to be the product of that:

> Failed to add recipient: yyy@yyy.nl [SMTP: Invalid response code
>   received from server (code: 550, response: R1: HELO should be a FQDN
>   or address literal (See RFC 2821
>   4.1.1.1))]**_____________________________________**

Which to me reads like you are having an SMTP connection issue.  The logic being:

1. The mailer fails with a SMTP error.
2. The code in `sendmail.php` is designed to output this error directly to the screen. Which sends headers the first time around.
3. Then the code in `mailer.php` fails because the headers were already sent by `sendmail.php`.

Which all means the SMTP connection might be broken for your config.  Looking at this code in `mailer.php`:

```
$host = "localhost";  
$username = "";     
$password = "";
```

And this below it:

```
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
    array ('host' => $host,
    'auth' => false,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password));
```

It seems like you were once able to connect via SMTP to `localhost` without a username or password at some point.  And now it suddenly stopped working that way.  Since `Mail::factory` seems  to be a part of the [PEAR Mail package](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.factory.php), I would recommend trying to change that to `sendmail` and see if that works on your `localhost`:

```
$smtp = Mail::factory('sendmail',
    array ('sendmail_path' => '/usr/bin/sendmail',
    'sendmail_args' => '-i'));
```

The config is adjusted to match the [PEAR Mail package](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.factory.php) manual `sendmail` specifications:

> $params["sendmail_path"] - The location of the sendmail program on the
>   filesystem. Default is /usr/bin/sendmail.
>
> $params["sendmail_args"] - Additional parameters to pass to the
>   sendmail. Default is -i.

You might need to change `/usr/bin/sendmail` to another path if that is not where `sendmail` is located on your server. Perhaps it would be in `/usr/local/bin/sendmail`? But try with `/usr/bin/sendmail` for now.

Comment: This is line 39: 'echo $result->getMessage() . "_________________________________________" . $mime->getMessage();
'. I don't see how that would be already sending the header...

Comment: I have just added the code to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Jake, thanks a lot for your extensive comment, I tried it with /usr/bin/sendmail and that unfortunately didn't fix the issue. I then tried with /usr/local/bin/sendmail, this added the following lines to the error the user receives in the browser: Warning: escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons in /usr/local/lib/php/Mail/sendmail.php on line 120

Warning: escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons in /usr/local/lib/php/Mail/sendmail.php on line 120

Warning: escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons in /usr/local/lib/php/Mail/sendmail.php on line 144

Comment: I'm not on a shared host, the company is renting its own server as far as I know. I will contact the original author of the code with your solution as I'm not yet sure how to effectively fix it. I do, however, now clearly understand what the issue is, so thank you for that.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that, I will make sure to contact them first thing in the morning and refer them back to this page. I'd up vote you if I had the reputation for it... ;-)

Comment: I unfortunately don't have such direct access to the server.